# BeautifulSoup: построчная обработка таблицы

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, пытаюсь обработать выгрузку информации о `Сisco` телефоне в формате `HTML`. Необходимые данные лежат в `table[2]`

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><TITLE>Cisco Systems, Inc.</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor="#FFFFFF" link="#FFFFFF" vlink="#FFFFFF" alink="#FFFFFF" text="#003031" >
<TABLE BORDER="1" WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="100%" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" bordercolor="#003031">
    <TR>
        <td WIDTH="200" HEIGHT="100" ALIGN=center><A HREF="http://www.cisco.com"><IMG SRC="/FS/Logo.png"></A></TD>
        <td HEIGHT="50" bgcolor="#003031"><p ALIGN=center style="margin-top: 0px;"><B><font color="#FFFFFF" size="6">Device information</FONT></B><p ALIGN=center><B><font color="#FFFFFF" size="4">Cisco IP Phone</FONT></FONT></B></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <td WIDTH="200" ALIGN=center VALIGN=top bgcolor="#003031">  
            <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLSPACING="10" CELLPADDING="0">     
                <TR><TD><a href="/CGI/Java/Serviceability?adapter=device.statistics.device">Device information</A></TD></TR>
                <TR><TD><B><font color='#FFFFFF'>Streaming statistics</FONT></B></TD></TR>
                <TR><TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/CGI/Java/Serviceability?adapter=device.statistics.streaming.0">Stream 1 </A></TD></TR>
             </TABLE>
        </TD>
        <td VALIGN=top>
            <DIV ALIGN=center>
                <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLSPACING="10" CELLPADDING="0">
                    <TR><TD><B> Service mode</B></TD><td width=20></TD><TD><B>Enterprise</B></TD></TR>
                    ...
                    <TR><TD><B> Service domain</B></TD><td width=20></TD><TD><B></B></TD></TR>
                    <TR><TD><B> App load ID</B></TD><td width=20></TD><TD><B>rootfs8845_65.12&#x2D;1&#x2D;1&#x2D;12</B></TD></TR>
                </TABLE>
            </DIV>
        </TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
</BODY></HTML>
```

При попытке вытащить параметры аппарата из таблицы,  не отображаются строки

```
param = soup.findChildren("table"[2])
print(param)
```

В выводе получается список без какой либо привязки к строкам, все параметры подряд:

```
....<b> Service mode</b>, <b>Enterprise</b>, <b> Service domain</b>, <b></b>, <b>   Service state</b>, <b>Idle</b>, ....
```

Однако если сделать поиск по тегу `"DIV"`

```
param = soup.findChildren("div")
print(param)
```

На выводе будет строка необходимых данных, но ее нельзя прогнать через цикл что бы  создать словарь, где параметры из одной строки будут ключом - значением (пример "Service mode" : "Enterprise")

Подскажите, как правильно обработать таблицу, чтобы создать словарь из параметров в `table[2]`

Comment: `"table"[2]` это не то, что вы ожидаете :)

Comment: Да, при этом получается, неупорядоченный набор данных из 2-х столбцов этой таблицы, и к тому же в некоторых строках данные могут быть только в одном столбце.

Comment: Потому что, `soup.findChildren("table"[2])` на самом деле станет `soup.findChildren("b")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# ...

table = root.select_one('table:nth-of-type(3)')
# Или так:
table = soup.select('table')[2]

name_by_value = dict()

for tr in table.select('tr'):
    tds = tr.select('td')
    name, value = tds[0].text.strip(), tds[2].text.strip()
    name_by_value[name] = value

print(name_by_value)
# {'Service mode': 'Enterprise', 'Service domain': '', 'App load ID': 'rootfs8845_65.12-1-1-12'}
```

---

**PS.**

Заметил, что нужные значения ячеек находятся исключительно в `<b>`, а значит можно немного конкретизировать поиск:

```
...

for tr in table.select('tr'):
    tds = [x.text.strip() for x in tr.select('td > b')]
    name, value = tds[0], tds[1]
    name_by_value[name] = value

...
```

А если элементов всегда ожидается два, то воспользоваться распаковкой:

```
...

for tr in table.select('tr'):
    name, value = [x.text.strip() for x in tr.select('td > b')]
    name_by_value[name] = value

...
```

Comment: Да, это именно то, что было необходимо, спасибо большое за решение!